# How to solve this error? Instance method '-attributesOfItemAtPath:eror:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: objective-c, macos, compiler-errors

I declare function in header KTLog.h.

```
 - (NSString *)logfileName;
```

And implements this in KTLog.m like,

```
- (NSString *)logfileName
 {
    NSString *logPath = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", NSHomeDirectory()]            stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Library/Logs/"];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isDir;

if (!([fm fileExistsAtPath:logPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir))
{
     NSURL *nsrulLogpath = [NSURL URLWithString:logPath];
    if (![fm createDirectoryAtURL:nsrulLogpath withIntermediateDirectories:nil attributes:nil error:nil])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create log directory: %@", logPath);
    }
}

NSString *processName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processName];
NSString *logName = [logPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"%@.ktlog", processName]];

 if (![fm fileExistsAtPath:logName])
 {
    if (![fm createFileAtPath:logName contents:[NSData data] attributes:nil])
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create log file at: %@", logName);
    }
}

return logName;
```

}

But when i call this function like this,

```
  NSDictionary *logAttribs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[self logfileName] eror:&error];
```

Its give error. I import KTLog.h in KTLog.m file. but i could not understand this error. Please help me.

Comment: Because you spelled error, as eror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss typed error.

```
 error:&error];
```